# Modify a local instance of own class

Tags: c++

I've got a class where one of the private properties is an instance of the class. In Java (because I'm used to Java) this looks like:

```
class Node {
    private Node Pi;
}
```

And now I'm writing this in C++, and when I try to do the same thing, I get a red underline (I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express), "Incomplete type is not allowed".

```
class Node {
    private:
        Node Pi; //Incomplete type is not allowed
};
```

I've tried fixing this by changing it to `Node Pi(void);` but then why I try to use another function that modifies this property I get "Expression must be a modifiable lvalue".

```
class Node {
    private:
        Node Pi(void);
    public:
        void setPi(Node n);
};
void Node::setPi(Node n) {
    Pi = n; //Node Node::Pi() expression must be a modifiable lvalue
}
```

Normally in Java there's no problem with this, so my question is, how do I implement this? I'm not a beginner to C++, but I haven't written with it for a while.

```
class Node {
    private Node Pi;
    void setPi(Node n) {
        this.Pi = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Incomplete type not allowed" means you can't create an instance of a class that hasn't been fully-defined yet.  A class isn't "complete" until the compiler reads its closing brace and semicolon.  A class can't contain an instance of itself; that'd be a circular definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn `Pi` into a reference or a pointer to `Node`.

1. A reference (`Node& Pi`) will result in nicer syntax, but can't be null, will have to be initialized at construction and cannot be changed to refer to a different object.
2. A pointer (`Node* Pi`) will require less pretty syntax, but can be null and can be made to point to different objects at different times.

For more details, see [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (Send pointer to objects instead of class objects directly)

```
class Node {
    private:
        Node* Pi(void);
    public:
        void setPi(Node* n);
};

void Node::setPi(Node* n) {
    Pi = n; //Node Node::Pi() expression must be a modifiable lvalue
}
```

Java 'auto-magically' converts those objects, with C++, you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Java's syntax hides the fact that it uses pointers everywhere. In C++ you have to use pointer syntax explicitly in order to mimic Java:

```
// Java
class Node {
    private Node Pi; // This is actually a pointer
}

// C++
class Node {
    private:
        Node *Pi; // So you use a pointer in C++ too
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code :

```
class Node {
    private:
        Node Pi; //Incomplete type is not allowed
};
```

To:

```
class Node {
    private:
        Node* Pi; 
};
```